# Asp.net core JWT with Google OAuth

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm new to asp.net core.
I'm trying to create a simple WEB API with asp.net which uses Jwt Token and Google OAuth.

About JWT, I've followed this tutorial and succeeded : https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core

But I don't know how to do my authentication with Google OAuth in my WEB API system. What I think about is :

- Because WEB API doesn't have view, a client app (Desktop App, iOS App) will get authentication code and exchange that code for access_token.
- Web API receives access_token comes from client, send request to Google to verify the token and do authentication.

My question is :

- Is my implementation correct?
- How to implement it by code ?

Thank you,

Comment: Google provide example c# code https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth